# Access Query Design View replicating criteria

Tags: ms-access

I am working on a form based parameter query and it was working great until today when I had to add new fields into my base table and edit the form accordingly.

When I entered my query in design view to add the new code, the code I have in place the criteria has repeated itself hundreds of times down the criteria rows and is adding its own columns.

If I delete the excess rows and columns the form stops returning any results; and deleting and re-creating the query generates the same problem.

I've attached a screenshot for reference.

Thank in advance for the help.

[Access Screen shot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jmZjY.jpg)

Comment: Yes, that will happen when using multiple OR operators. If you get the desired output don't worry about how Access configures the SQL. I NEVER use dynamic parameterized queries. I use VBA to build filter string and apply to form or report.

Comment: It is not replicating anything - it's simply how to fulfill your criteria. No problem.

Comment: The problem is I can't change or edit any of the criteria; access states there isn't enough memory to save any changes.

Answer (score 0):

This has been solved. I was able to find another example on another forum and moved the coding into the "Field" field on the query and added an additional tage.